# Graph API returning blank 1x1 pixel image

Tags: facebook, json, encoding

When I use the Graph API to get a list of posts from a page, the picture field, which contains the URL for the image returns a blank 1x1 pixel image.

For example, this is one of the URLs that it returns:
http://www.facebook.com/l.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fexternal.ak.fbcdn.net%2Fsafe_image.php%3Fd%3DAQBj9y7r5zdKLsTF%26w%3D90%26h%3D90%26url%3Dhttp%5Cu00253A%5Cu00252F%5Cu00252Fwww.thisislondon.co.uk%5Cu00252Fincoming%5Cu00252Farticle7630373.ece%5Cu00252FBINARY%5Cu00252Foriginal%5Cu00252FTerry-Deary.jpg&h=GAQEzRMSC

I've also seen this using the RSS feed from the page: https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=128931583879163&format=rss20 except that the URLs are encoded slightly differently.

I've had a good look on stackoverflow, but haven't seen anyone else with the same problem.  Could you tell me what I need to do to decode it to get the appropriate URL please?

Thanks,
Gregor

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug, as reported on the Facebook Developer site, for both [pictures](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/352719024770077) and [video](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/358888337475544). The issue is still pending a fix from Facebook.

Comment: Links are broken as of '14

Comment: Are links fine now? Coz I am still getting blank images.

Comment: And me... when posting with the graph API and object_attachment

Answer (score 1):

(MacBook)-I was receiving this as well, but only when I was on  my dashboard page. After several seconds, the dashboard page would slide to the blank Facebook pixel page.This was driving me crazy.  I finally deleted my dashboard page, which i really didn't use anyway, by using a code and running it on terminal. (from "how to hide or disable the dashboard page). The docking page disappeared and so did the 1x1 pixel page. I can restore the docking page whenever i want by using a second code.